# How to change defined device screen size?

Tags: android

I have a noname Android tab with 7 inch display, but in the firmware it's defined as 9 inch, so the dpi is calculated incorrectly. How can I change the defined display size to the correct 7 inch, if I have root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your build.prop file:

```
ro.sf.lcd_density = $desired_value
```

Refer to http://www.freeyourandroid.com/guide/how-to-edit-build-prop to know how to do this with a file manager.